Clarification on process for unwrapping and sending to Substance Painter
I dont think Im stuck here, I just want someone more skilled than I am to give me some reassurance that Im heading in right direction.
The issue.
Attempting to get a BIM model from Revit into Blender, through to Substance Painter and back to a realtime rendered called D5. So far its working but not sure if IM doing it the right way.
This is my process

Ive remeshed the BIM model and cleaned up.
Unwrapped with box projection for simple shapes
Apply texel density of 1024 px/m with Texel Density Checker
Apply mapping node to make sure texture repeats across object
Pack uv islands using UVPackmaster
Send to substance painter using plugin.
Bake and set textures at 4k in substance
Sync and output to D5.


Its all working but Im still having to scale up my textures in substance painter to get detail and then also in D5 the texture appears blurry in the foreground.
Is this the right approach?


If you’re having to scale up your textures Blender with the mapping node, that means the mesh is not unwrapped properly. UV maps can extend outside UV bounds without scaling them up via nodes. Show a screenshot of the UV Editor, with the object in question selected in the 3D Viewport, and the texture in question chosen from the UV editor’s header.

Thankyou! Ive created a short video which helps explain what Im doing wrong, it might help to explain the issue and whether you can identify where Im messing up. Heres the youtube link
https://youtu.be/9uz5fb8HqmY

You do not have to “pack” the UVs all into the image bounds, and in fact you don’t want to given your desired result. The UVs of the vast majority of game models are not constrained to the image bounds and they don’t have to be. I’m not sure what the Texel addon does, but it seems like it basically sets them to not be constrained by the image bounds to give the desired scale, and then you’re turning around and undoing that with UV pack master.

Side note, Reddit is currently the Harry & JoJo of advice. There is no reason to use the remesh modifiers here, and there’s no reason to use “convert to mesh“ instead of just applying the modifiers normally if they were needed.

Thanks @TheLabCat Appreciated.
I think I am needing to pack the islands into the image bounds as without this when I bake maps in substance, some of them dont back to the UV correctly.
The Texel addon simply helps me manage the Texel Density across mutliple objects, thats all Im using it for which seems to work OK.
Thanks for the suggestion on not having to remesh, Ive done that now and it maps OK still so thats saved a step.
I think its best if I set the uvimage to 4K, set the maximum texel density I can reasonably achieve and then tile in substance if its needed. Thankyou!

Ohh, baking... Yeah, that does require the maps to all be within the image bounds. Hmm. You could use two UV maps on the same mesh, but IDK if your overall work flow could support that.
